# Android Studio: Changing layout resource file causes error

Tags: android, layout

I got an error while changing the resource file name on the OnCreate() method and running it.

Here is the error:

```
05-21 18:37:29.553 29635-29635/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment-1/lib/x86
05-21 18:37:29.860 29635-29635/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment-1/lib/x86
05-21 18:37:29.941 29635-29635/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-21 18:37:29.944 29635-29635/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-21 18:37:29.945 29635-29635/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment, PID: 29635
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment/com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) '
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.gamecodeschool.linearlayoutexperiment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linear_experiment);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I cant change the layout resource file name from activity_main to anything other file name. I am just starting to learn android development and this is really confusing for me.

Comment: You are getting a null pointer exception which is causing the Run time exception. It says right there in the log cat that the floating action button is null yet you are trying to use one of its methods. You need to see if the FAB widget ID is on the layout file being inflated.

Comment: I am sorry if this is stupid question to ask but what is a floating action button?

Comment: I added 3 plain text views and 2 buttons on the display if that is what u are saying

Comment: Look at your onCreate method where you put the floating action button.